# RESTful api design, HATEOAS and resource discovery

Tags: api, rest, hateoas

One of the core ideas behind HATEOAS is that clients should be able to start from single entry point URL and discover all exposed resources and state transitions available for those. While I can perfectly see how that works with HTML and a human behind a browser clicking on links and "Submit" buttons, I'm quizzed about how this principle can be applied to problems I'm (un)lucky to deal with.

I like how RESTful design principle is presented in papers and educational articles where it all makes sense, [How to GET a Cup of Coffee](http://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow) is a good example of such. I'll try to follow convention and come up with an example which is simple and free from tedious details. Let's look at zip codes and cities.

### Problem 1

Let's say I want to design RESTful api for finding cities by zip codes. I come up with resources called 'cities' nested into zip codes, so that GET on `http://api.addressbook.com/zip_codes/02125/cities` returns document containing, say, two records which represent Dorchester and Boston.

My question is: how such url can be discovered through HATEOAS? It's probably impractical to expose index of all ~40K zip codes under `http://api.addressbook.com/zip_codes`. Even if it's not a problem to have 40K item index, remember that I've made this example up and there are collections of much greater magnitude out there.

So essentially, I would want to expose not link, but link template, rather, like this: `http://api.addressbook.com/zip_codes/{:zip_code}/cities`, and that goes against principles and relies on out-of-band knowledge possessed by a client.

### Problem 2

Let's say I want to expose cities index with certain filtering capabilities:

- GET on `http://api.addressbook.com/cities?name=X` would return only cities with names matching `X`.
- GET on `http://api.addressbook.com/cities?min_population=Y` would only return cities with population equal or greater than `Y`.

Of course these two filters can be used together: `http://api.addressbook.com/cities?name=X&min_population=Y`.

Here I'd like to expose not only url, but also these two possible query options and the fact that they can be combined. This seems to be simply impossible without client's out-of-band knowledge of semantics of those filters and principles behind combining them into dynamic URLs.

So how principles behind HATEOAS can help making such trivial API really RESTful?

Comment: btw I'm also exploring options for api versioning and that's why it's tempting to have single entry point for each version. Something along [these lines](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/10/25/web_api_versioning_smackdown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using XHTML forms:

```
GET /

HTTP/1.1 OK

<form method="get" action="/zip_code_search" rel="http://api.addressbook.com/rels/zip_code_search">
   <p>Zip code search</p>
   <input name="zip_code"/>
</form>

GET /zip_code_search?zip_code=02125

HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: /zip_code/02125
```

What's missing in HTML is a `rel` attribute for `form`.

Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx):

> To summarize, there are several reasons to consider XHTML as the
>   default representation for your RESTful services. First, you can
>   leverage the syntax and semantics for important elements like `<a>`,
>   `<form>`, and `<input>` instead of inventing your own. Second, you'll end
>   up with services that feel a lot like sites because they'll be
>   browsable by both users and applications. The XHTML is still
>   interpreted by a human—it's just a programmer during development
>   instead of a user at runtime. This simplifies things throughout the
>   development process and makes it easier for consumers to learn how
>   your service works. And finally, you can leverage standard Web
>   development frameworks to build your RESTful services.

Also check out [OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/).

---

To reduce the number of request consider this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Location: /zip_code/02125

<html>
<head>
<link href="/zip_code/02125/cities" rel="related http://api.addressbook.com/rels/zip_code/cities"/>
</head>
...
</html>
```

Comment: This is interesting and it helps with problem 2, but how can you represent problem 1 with a form? Likewise for specific requirements for HTTP headers. I think that XHTML forms are much less expressive than WADL.

Comment: @Chris Dolan: My example was about Problem 1. Another way to solve it is using URI templates. I agree WADL is more complete, but with XHTML you get a UI for free. WADL with an `<?xml-stylesheet?>` should be sweet.

Comment: yes, but you ignored his API which was `/zip_codes/{:zip_code}/cities` where you defined `/zip_code_search?zip_code={:zipcode}` -- not at all the same and quite a bit easier with xhtml. Nonetheless, I think we actually are not that far from agreement. A quick search revealed some stylesheets I think would work: https://github.com/ipcsystems/wadl-stylesheet and https://github.com/mnot/wadl_stylesheets (I prefer the former)

Comment: @Chris Dolan: Note that the response contains a `Location` header with a link to `/zip_codes/{zip_code}`. To avoid too many request the response could be an OK and contain the zip_code representation, with a `Content-Location: /zip_codes/{zip_code}` header, and a link to cities in the representation.

Answer (score 2):

This solution comes to mind, but I'm not sure that I'd actually *recommend* it: instead of returning a resource URL, return a WADL URL that describes the endpoint. Example:

```
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <grammars/>
  <resources base="http://localhost:8080/cities">
    <resource path="/">
      <method name="GET">
        <request>
          <param name="name" style="query" type="xs:string"/>
          <param name="min-population" style="query" type="xs:int"/>
        </request>
        <response>
          <representation mediaType="application/octet-stream"/>
        </response>
      </method>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</application>
```

That example was autogenerated by CXF from this Java code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class Cities {
    @GET
    public Response get(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("min-population") int min_poulation) {
        // TODO: build the real response
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed answer! WADL is reasonable way to go, but wouldn't that immediately bring us closer to SOAP domain? I thought that HATEOAS is opposite to that, as I figured from the "GET coffee" example and other papers like that.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not actually recommending this solution! It's just one possibility. I don't think it's nearly as complicated as WSDL/SOAP. Yes, it's more formal than "zip_codes/{:zip_code}/cities" but it has a lot more flexibility and is machine readable. An implicit point of HATEOAS is machine-readability of the REST API, right? Well, I think of this as just one more step in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to question 1, I'm assuming your single entry point is `http://api.addressbook.com/zip_codes`, and the intention, is to enable the client to traverse the entire collection of zip codes and ultimately retrieve the cities related to them.

In which case i would make the `http://api.addressbook.com/zip_codes` resource return a redirect to the first page of zip codes, for example:

`http://api.addressbook.com/zip_codes?start=0&end=xxxx`

This would contain a "page" worth of zip code links (whatever number is suitable for the system to handle, plus a link to the next page (and previous page if there is one).

This would enable a client to crawl the entire list of zip codes if it so desired.

The urls returned in each page would look similar to this:

`http://api.addressbook.com/zip_codes/02125`

And then it would be a matter of deciding whether to include the city information in the representation returned by a zip code URL, or the link to it depending on the need.

Now the client has a choice whether to traverse the entire list of zip codes and then request the zipcode (and then cities) for each, or request a page of zip codes, and then request drill down to a parti

Answer (score 1):

I was running into these same questions - so I worked through a practical example that solves both of these problems (and a few you haven't thought of yet). http://thereisnorightway.blogspot.com/2012/05/api-example-using-rest.html?m=1

Basically, the solution to problem 1 is that you change your representation (as Roy says, spend your time on the resource).  You don't have to return all zips, just make your resource contain paging. As an example, when you request news pages from a news site - it gives you todays news, and links to more, even though all the articles may live under the same url structure, I.e. ...article/123, etc

Problem 2 is a little ackward - there is a little used command in http called OPTIONS that I used in the example to basically reflect the url's capability - although you could solve this in the representation too, it would just be more complicated.  Basically, it gives back a custom structure that shows the capabilities of the resource (including optional parameters).

Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you skipped over the bookmark URL. That is the first url, not the ones to get cities or zip codes.

So you start at ab:=http://api.addressbook.com

This first link returns back a list of available links. This is how the web works. You go to www.yahoo.com and then you start clicking links not knowing where they go.

So from the original link ab: you would get back the other links and they could have REL links that explain how those resources should be accessed or what parameters can be submitted.

The first think we did when designing our systems is to start from the bookmark page and determine all the different links that could be accessed.

I do agree with you about the 'client's out-of-band knowledge of semantics of those filters' it's hard for me to buy that a machine can just adapt to what is there unless it had some preconceived specification like HTML. It's more likely that the client is built by a developer who knows all the possibilities and then codes the application to 'potentially' expect those links to be available. If the link is available then the program can use the logic the developer implemented prior to act the resource.  If it's not there then it just doesn't execute the link. In the end possible paths are laid out prior to beginning to traverse the application.